# Access the generics arguments from a class in D

Tags: d

I have a class, that takes one generic argument

```
class A(T) {}
```

And I want to be able to access the value of that.

How can I do this.

I though that I might be able to write a function inside A that returns T, is this a good idea, or is there another way to access the type argument T outside the class A?

Comment: Nitpick: They're template arguments, not generics. Templates are much more powerful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an alias to T inside A that will return the actual "value" (type) of T. For example:

```
class A(T)
{
    alias type = T;
}

auto a = new A!int();
assert(is(a.type == int));
```

I've created a new `A!int` at runtime just for illustration. `type` is a sort of static member of `A!T` which you can access at compile time.

```
assert(is(A!double.type == double));
```

You can also easily extract the type that `A` was instantiated with using a template:

```
alias InstantiationType(_: u!T, alias u, T) = T;
assert(is(InstantiationType!(A!int) == int));
```

Luckily, as was mentioned, this functionality comes prepackaged in Phobos' std.traits in the form of [TemplateArgsOf](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#TemplateArgsOf).

Answer (score 4):

[TemplateArgsOf](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#TemplateArgsOf) in std.traits should do what you want.